# Should I use 'denote' or 'denotes' for several letters?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Do I need to use *denote* or *denotes* in the following math task?

> Given O <sup>、</sup>A <sup>、</sup>B <sup>、</sup>C
> denotes the points x <sup>、</sup>-2 <sup>、</sup>2
> <sup>、</sup>6 on a number line <sup>,</sup> what value must x
> be to minimize O͞A<sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup></sup> +
> O͞B<sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup></sup> +
> O͞C<sup><sup><sup>2</sup></sup></sup>?

Comment: John, Mary and Teddy go to the park together.

Comment: Please don't use O for any point other than the origin.

Comment: @JamesK - Why not?

Comment: Convention. The origin is by convention O,  and so OA is the position vector of the point A etc.  If you break the convention cause confusion for no apparent gain.

Comment: @JamesK - I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematician here.

I think phrasing is much better:

> Let (A,B, C) = (-2, 2, 6). Find the value of x that minimizes ...

If you must use "denote" say

> Let 0, A, B, C denote x, -2, 2, 6 ...